How to get buidinfo directly in yocto building environment?
We can get build info if we add this line:
INHERIT += "image-buildinfo"

ref:
https://wiki.koansoftware.com/index.php/Add_build_information_into_a_Yocto_image
However, the information was stored on the Yocto disk; what if I want this information directly in the build environment?
Edit:
I don't want to add or modify any recipe, so can I do it simply as below?
bitbake --some_paramters


In a suitable place of your distro:
IMAGE_PREPROCESS_COMMAND:remove = "buildinfo_image"

python buildinfo_deploy () {_
    d.setVar("BUILDINFODEST", "${DEPLOY_DIR}")
    bb.build.exec_func("buildinfo", d)
}

IMAGE_PREPROCESS_COMMAND += "buildinfo_deploy"

This removes the standard implementation of buildinfo and adds a custom one, generating the file in your deploy folder (e.g. ./build/tmp/deploy/etc).
